# Condensing Powershell Nested If/ElseIf

Tags: powershell

I've got a bit of a query on condensing some code. Using it in a function or two I am writing. First up some examples.

This is the If/ElseIf method.

```
If ($aVar -eq 1) {
    If ($bVar -le $cVar) {
        # code
        # code
        # code
        # code
    }
}
ElseIf ($aVar -eq 2) {
    If ($bVar -gt $cVar) {
        # code
        # code
        # code
        # code
    }
}
```

And here's the Switch method.

```
Switch ($aVar) {
    {$_ -eq 1} { 
        If ($bVar -le $cVar) {
            #code 
            #code 
            #code 
            #code 
        }
    }
    {$_ -eq 2} { 
        If ($bVar -gt $cVar) {
            #code 
            #code 
            #code 
            #code 
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to condense this at all?

The #code sections are the exact same, so was wondering if there'd be a way of only writing it once instead of having it twice in either method used.

Thanks!

Comment: Write a function and call it wherever you want.

Comment: Do you want to condense the conditionals or just re-use the `#code` parts? Is the second conditional supposed to be part of the re-used code?

Comment: Bill, you're just suggesting nesting another function within the "master" function?

Condensing the conditional if's would be ideal, but I'm not sure how I'd manage that. Only the #code sections are the static code that is identical - if I can only write this once, that'd be great. Maybe function is how I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the -OR and -AND arguments?

```
If(($aVar -eq 1 -and $bVar -le $cVar) -or ($aVar -eq 2 -and $bVar -gt $cVar)){
    #code
    #code
    #code
    #code
}
```